# Libreoffice does not have my interface language

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

My Libreoffice install (the latest/stable from Snap) does not let me select a Norwegian interface.

I have my language (norsk bokmål) selected in the language support settings, and I have verified that libreoffice-l10n-nb is installed. Despite this, there is no Norwegian interface language choice in Libreoffice.

(Nor was there a Norwegian spell checker, but I solved that through installing a LibreOffice extension.)

Comment: Both issues seem to be snap related. With LibreOffice installed via a `.deb` file I have no problem to set both the display language and the spellchecking language to Norwegian bokmål (for the latter I installed the `hunspell.no` package). So it would be good if you could file a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bugs?field.tag=snap).

Comment: Takk! I tried re-installing using `sudo apt install libreoffice-gnome libreoffice libreoffice-l10n-nb`, and that works fine. One problem with it though—I don't seem to have the program that's just "libreoffice", where you can open any file, and it'll launch the correct libreoffice program. Do I need an additional package for this?

Comment: In previous Ubuntu versions it's there, but 'hidden'. That was [fixed in 21.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu2). You should still be able to start with `libreoffice` via <Alt>+F2 or the terminal.

Comment: Thanks! I read up on it and found out why they changed it. I don't agree with their reasoning, so I just copied the .desktop file from /usr/share/applications to ~/.local/, and commented out the line that hides it from GNOME.